# Github README Render Gliffy diagrams

Tags: github, readme, gliffy

Is there a way to add a gliffy diagram in the README of a github repo? I know how to add an image and I have tried that approach with gliffy diagram but it does not work; the gliffy does not render. Perhaps the correct question is, is there a gliffy renderer for the github READMEs?

**EDIT:**

What I really want is to maybe store the gliffy xml in the repo that will automatically get rendered in the README when referenced, instead of storing the xml *and* the pre-rendered image in the repo.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @igracia I did not. I am still interested in finding an answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

What is the URL of your diagram? I don't have Gliffy, but I think you should just do something like this:

```
![Your Gliffy Diagram Name](//www.gliffy.com/go/publish/image/...)
```

Where `...` means everything after the url.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31208778)